# Bad Jew or Good Gentile?

Tags: gentiles, hashkafah-philosophy, eretz-yisrael, theology, ahavat-yisrael

Whom does Hashem love more: Gentiles who love Jewish people and Israel or Jews who are against Jewish people and Israel?

Comment: On second thought, I went ahead and took out "heathen" myself. Please still edit in your clarification, but I'd advise you to avoid singling out specific people for criticism, to ensure that the discussion stays focused on the principles rather than contemporary politics.

Comment: How can God love?  Love is something that humans do, and God is super-human.

Comment: @AdamMosheh  [וַאֲהֵבְךָ, וּבֵרַכְךָ וְהִרְבֶּךָ](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0507.htm#13). How? [Ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I've read in one of Rabbi Avigdor Miller's Thursday Night Q&A books outright that Hashem is happier with the best gentile than the worst jew, but the worst jew has more potential.

Comment: Note: this is the secret to "ad delo yada".

Comment: Why is this question limited to only love, or are you using love in a more general sense? If so could you define it?

Answer (score 10):

Just as a first crack at this (and there is a lot more to say on the topic), we need to distinguish between different kinds of love. In human terms, a person loves their spouse, their children, and their close friends; but each of these is of a different type. Some of these may be "a love dependent on an external factor," others, "a love not dependent on such factors" (see Ethics of the Fathers 5:16).

In somewhat the same way (to the extent that we can apply human terms to G-d at all), there is a difference between a Jew - who, as low as he or she may have fallen, is still a Jew and a "child of G-d" (Deut. 14:1 and R' Meir in Talmud, Kiddushin 36a, explaining this verse), and with whom He therefore has a supra-rational and indissoluble bond -

versus a non-Jew, who does not have that special relationship (although it is of course true that G-d appreciates and rewards his or her good deeds - see Talmud, Bava Kamma 38b).

Comment: What's to say that G-d doesn't have different special relationships with non-Jewish groups?

Answer (score 4):

Fascinating question.  I would like to clarify a few things.  First, I would like to make explicitly clear what you mean by "Hashem Loves more".  In a strict sense Hashem does not love.  He being perfect does not have any emotions.
    The Rambam states in the Moreh Nevuchim, Book I, Chapter 55 that no change or emotion can ever be predicated of Hashem.  As the Novie states in Malachi Perek Gimmel, Pasuk Vov,  "I, G-d, do not change."
    Rambam states in the Yad, Laws Concerning the Fundementals of our Faith, Perek Alef, Halacha Yud Alef, "and He does not change, for there is nothing that can cause change in him.  There does not exist in him... anger or laughter, happiness or sadness…"

Therefore we can not say that Hashem loves us, that would be attributing an emotion to Hashem.
However, I believe your fundemental question is to identify which person is considered on a higher level before Hashem.  An Idolater who loves Jews or a Jewish person that hates Jews.  This is a challenging question, because the idolater is far from reality and the truth in that he has a false idea about God.  The hating Jew must also be distorting the truth in order to hate the Jewish people.  So, both are distant form reality.  One would need to delve further to understand why it is that the non-Jews loves the Jews and why the Hating Jew hates other Jews?  What is the basis for the hate,  Perhaps if one is more correctable, then they may be in a better position to change.
Just a few thoughts to address your question, let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: "I loved Jacob, but Esau I hated"....

Comment: @Gary are you asking a question?  If so, can you clarify?

Comment: -I can make it into a question-I'm far from an expert on the later commentators, but there's plenty of places in Tanach where God shows emotions, or plainly states his feelings.  How can you say He does not love, when He says it?  And why would perfection not include emotions? IMHO, perfection includes a bit of all emotions. "..whose Name is Jealous""His anger flared, and a fire from **** burned among them""My wrath will be kindled"  etc. It's only us humans that assign good and bad labels to emotions, and think ourselves into a philosophical/logical conclusion that God doesn't have them.

Comment: @Gary Malachi 1:3, “Esau I hated.” does not refer to Jacob’s brother, but the nation, and even this is a metaphor. The Rambam felt that G-d does not have emotions.

Comment: @Gary God does not hate Esau. That is attributing to God a human emotion and God has no emotions!

Comment: @Gary God has no emotions such as anger, hate, and love.

Comment: @Gary Why do you think to be perfect God must have human emotions? It is a perfection in God not have have emotions. God never gets emotional.

Comment: @Gary An idea of a jealous God is idolatrous. Jealousy is the offspring of finite minds, proceeding from the want of knowledge; but in God who is all-knowing there can be no jealousy, for knowledge excludes it. Jealousy can have no existence in God, which possesses perfect knowledge, and consequently cannot be ascribed to God, who knows all things.

Answer (score 1):

Abraham was a prophet, and more perfected than anyone. Jews and Rabbis are included. He was not Jewish, and yet God loved him.

The Talmud says: “A gentile who studies Torah is akin to a High Priest.”[1] And in 45:1 the prophet Isaiah calls the non-Israelite Cyrus “God’s Messiah.” A person who is Jewish has no advantage over the gentile. Being Jewish only means that you are liable to the penalties for breaking God's laws. But a gentile may follow God and be considered righteous just as the born Jew.

A gentile who found God is perfected. Jews who ignore God's laws are less perfected than this gentile.

[1] Talmud Sanhedrin 59a

Answer (score 0):

who does a father love more? his own children or someone else's?

Comment: God has children?

Comment: If covenant is the issue, perhaps wife or hordes of girlfriends would be a better analogy.

Comment: @JimThio The relationship between G-d and the Jews is a complex and multifaceted one. The Jews are at times called G-d's children, daughter, wife, mother, and servants. It is never meant in the literal physical sense of the word, but rather in a spiritual and (cringe) metaphorical sense.

Comment: We are all b'nei adam. Who is this "someone else"?

Comment: To say that God has children is on the edge of blasphemy. God loves Gentiles who love Jews and Israel more than self-hating Jews who stand against Israel. The evidence of this can be found in the Bible itself. An earthquake swallowed up Korah, Dathan, and Abiram but God saved Noah, a righteous non-Jew.

Comment: @Shmuel "_To say that God has children is on the edge of blasphemy._" [Devarim 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.14.1?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: @TamirEvan It not to be taken literally.

Comment: @Shmuel (1) Who says the answer is taking it literally? (2) As a metaphor, something is to be learned from the analogy. Why not this?

Comment: @TamirEvan God can’t love Jews more than non-Jews because (1) God has no human emotions and (2) He created both Jew and gentile. God never destroyed Adam and create another kind of man. We all descend from Adam and Eve.

Comment: @Shmuel "_God can’t love Jews more than non-Jews because (1) God has no human emotions and (2) He created both Jew and gentile._" Yet, in the words of his prophet, He says([Malachi 1:2-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malachi.1.2-3?ven=The_Holy_Scriptures:_A_New_Translation_(JPS_1917)&lang=bi&lang2=en)):"_I have loved you, saith the LORD_ ... _yet I loved Jacob; But Esau I hated_ ...". Even if it was only said metaphorically, still some analogy is meant to be drawn from that wording. Also, _you_ brought two answers, that state "God loves/loved", and that argued He loves some Gentiles _more_.

Comment: @Shmuel  "_God never destroyed Adam and create another kind of man. We all descend from Adam and Eve._" Yet, God did destroy all sons of Adam, besides Noah in the Deluge, and none of us are descendants of Adam and Eve, that aren't descendants of Noah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146832/discussion-between-shmuel-and-tamir-evan).

Comment: @TamirEvan We all descend from Adam and Eve through Noah, so, your point is mute.

Comment: @TamirEvan I’ve already explained this to be a metaphor. God did not hate Esau. God has no human emotions! 

Actually, Esau was given a bad rap. He’s actually a really chill dude if you get to know him. He’s not as bad as they say. Read the Bible.

Answer (score 0):

> Whom does Hashem love more: Gentiles who love Jewish people and Israel
> or Jews who are against Jewish people and Israel?

First of all to clarify, whether you are pro or anti zionism, Israel (as the secular state) is not of particular significance in Yiddishkeit (Judaism). While Eretz Yisrael (the land of Israel) does, the secular state established in Eretz Yisrael isn't anything from the Torah.

In regards to the question, Hashem loves all of us (Jews) whatever we do. Hashem never stops loving us.
We are Hashem's am hanivchar, his chosen people. No matter what we do, Hashem will always love us more than a non-Jew - its like asking (lehavdil) 'what does a parent love more, their kid who breaks all their rules and is a total degenerate, or the kid next door who is a nice kid'. We are Hashem's children, his am hanivchar - he will always love us.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand question right way. As many mentioned here probably question should not be about love. I would say rather who's soul seems better or who is greater son of Noah who keeps all 7 rules or Jew that is full of sins.

**Of course non-jew!**

At least he does his obligations.

Being jewish it means he must keep more commandments, more responsibility, more obligations.

Jewish has a higher potential, but it doesn't mean he is full of light when son of Noah is keeping all his obligations will have more light than a Jew who doesn't do anything.

There are 2 cups with size of 7 and 613.

First one is full of water.

Second one is empty.

Where there is a more water?

Comment: Any sources for you position?

Comment: @Harel13 it's very simple, there are 7 Noah commandments, they keep they are alive since days of Noah and nothing got changed, after we see there were jews praying to golden calf breaking most important commandment - they are dead by levites Exodus 32:28.

Comment: Any sources you have edit into your answer, as well as doing so going forward.

Answer (score 0):

God loves Gentiles who love Jews and Israel more than self-hating Jews who stand against Israel. The evidence of this can be found in the Bible itself. An earthquake swallowed up Korah, Dathan, and Abiram but God saved Noah, a righteous non-Jew.

Comment: "_The evidence of this can be found in the Bible itself. An earthquake swallowed up Korah, Dathan, and Abiram_ ..." How do you know that earthquake swallowed up Korah, Dathan, and Abiram was because God loved them less? The Talmud ([Yevamot 121b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.121b.8?lang=bi&lang2=en)) says: "'_And around Him it storms_ [נשערה] _mightily_ (Psalms 50:3) _which teaches that the Holy One, Blessed be He, is exacting with His surroundings_ [i.e., the righteous who are close to Him] _up to a hairsbreadth_ [שערה], [so that even slight deviations can elicit severe punishment]."

Comment: @TamirEvan If God loved Jews more He would not have subjected them to this punishment. I could give you a Talmudic source where God mourns the Egyptians drowning in the Red Sea.

Comment: "_If God loved Jews more He would not have subjected them to this punishment._" How do you know what [kind of] punishment comes from loving less, as opposed to being exacting towards those closest to him?

Comment: @TamirEvan God lacks human emotions. But if we are to use the term, then we should treat God as God wants to be treated. God loves everyone and everyone is chosen. “God is to all men equally gracious, (and the Hebrews were only chosen  in respect to their social government). There is no difference between Jew and Gentile. It is a fact that God is equally gracious, merciful, and the rest, to all men; and God has not chosen one people rather than another.“ — Spinoza