# Would a non-Jew sin if he were to proclaim himself a Jew for the sake of solidarity?

Tags: gentiles, sin

For those interested, I'll also be asking this question on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38012/would-a-non-muslim-sin-if-here-to-proclaim-himself-a-muslim-for-the-sake-of-soli) and [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55372/would-a-non-christian-sin-if-here-to-proclaim-himself-a-christian-for-the-sake-o) (with respect to those religions)

In recent rallies protesting what is perceived as bigoted policies by President Donald Trump, several individuals who are not in fact Muslim and do not subscribe to the Islamic faith have claimed they are Muslim in a show of solidarity with the Muslim world.

I'm curious if, if a non-Jew were to claim Judaism, it would be a specific sin. While I generally understand that not subscribing to the faith in general is sinful, I'm curious about the act of proclaiming that you are an adherent when that is not true. (I'm asking in particular about the sin of falsely claiming adherence to the faith, this should be understood as being a different or greater-magnitude sin than simply violating any general rules about lying or telling falsehoods.)

Comment: `While I generally understand that not subscribing to the faith in general is sinful` Actually not. Jews do not demand that non-Jews become Jewish. Righteous gentiles are entitled to the World to Come, for example. See for example, here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14466/8775.

Comment: In general proving a negative is very difficult, so if the answer to questions like these is no, they very often fail to receive good answers. | I strongly suspect that in a vacuum, the act of falsely proclaiming to be Jewish, is not considered a sin.

Comment: @mevaqesh That would actually be an excellent answer! It debunks the premise of the question  -- being a gentile is not a sin, so the worst thing the person would be doing is lying, which per the question is excluded from consideration

Comment: While it certainly increases the likelihood that the answer to the question is 'no', it doesn't prove it. As I mentioned in the previous comment, proving negatives is very difficult. It just removes one reason why it might be prohibited. It could still theoretically be prohibited, even though as I stated, AFAIK it isn't.

Comment: @mevaqesh Someone who claims to be Jewish in order to be counted for a minyan or to eat from the korbon Pesach would be a different situation from trying to show solidarity in a political context. During World War II the Nazi's (*Ymach Shmam Vezichram*) called for the Jews in a captured group of U.S. soldiers to step forward. The NCO in charge (not Jewish) stepped forward followed by every member of his group.  [Yad Vashem honors American GI who told Nazis 'We are all Jews'](http://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Yad-Vashem-honors-American-GI-who-told-Nazis-We-are-all-Jews-436103)

Comment: @sabbahillel Thats why I wrote: "I strongly suspect that **in a vacuum, the act of falsely proclaiming to be Jewish**, is not considered a sin." | To limit it to the OP's question. Certainly external factors can affect things in practical cases.

Comment: @mevaqesh I gave the two extreme examples because it is impossible to act **in a vaccuum**. I also suspect that the rallies and protests are not a good example. However, that is a political argument that should not apply here.