How to deal with non-Jews claiming to be Jews?
I ask this because I know this fellow who claims to be a Jew. He was notorious for so many things back in high school and some time after graduation, he came out as a bisexual and fell out with his high school friends as a result.
I reached out to him and talked with him about Judaism, particulalry his observance (or lack thereof.) Then he revealed to me that he is actually Messianic. He still considers himself a "Jew" even though he is not devout (to his faith). I confronted him that he should stop calling himself a Jew because he objectively is not one but he unfortunately persists.
The worst part about this is that I can only imagine the negative perceptions he may have conjured or even reinforced about Jews among those who are under the impression that he is a Jew and also know of his notoriety. I tried mitigating this by talking to some of his former pals back in high school, explaining to them that he is not a Jew, but a messianic. Unfortunately, they, perhaps out of antisemitism, seem to persist in regarding him as a Jew.
How does one deal with a situation like this, where a gentile falsely claims to be a Jew and gives Jews a bad name as a result of his terrible behavior?

You should not believe a signgle word of this person. Stay away from him, and the fact that you are not with him is a good enough proof that he is not representing Jewish community. One cannot even establish if he is really "messianic" or just trolling you. I used to work with one etnically greek guy from Brooklyn, who told me that as a misbehaving teenager he used to add -owitz to his last name so that police officers would not suspect him of the trouble. Learn karate and be ready to defend yourself from thugs like that.

@YDJ Appreciate the advice. He is indeed messianic and it shows from his lack of basic knowledge about Judaism and he always refers to G-d as Y--WE-. As of late, he seems to have turned his back on being a messianic due to his sexual orientation.

1st question is he ethnically Jewish? Your points seem to be about heresy.

@הראל No, he is not an ethnic Jew. Is it heresy? I think it's more about a non-Jew fuelling antisemitism by pretending to be a Jew and behaving terribly.

"Then he revealed to me that he is actually Messianic. He still considers himself a 'Jew' even though he is not devout (to his faith)." Technically, he can be a Jew, by matrilineal descent (he could even have been born a Jew, and brought up as one), and profess non-Jewish beliefs (as an adult). Being Messianic does not automatically exclude the possibility of him being a Jew.

"How does one deal with a situation like this, where a gentile falsely claims to be a Jew and gives Jews a bad name as a result of his terrible behavior?" Why not the same way members of any other group deal with non-members who falsely claim to be members, and give the group a bad name as a result of their terrible behavior?

Don't count him in a minyan, eat food "fit for a king's table" he cooks, or drink wine he's touched. That's how we treat non-Jews.

Not sure how to answer this, and not sure if it is appropriate for this site. It's impossible to answer because the whole entire situation, with far too much detail for what you are able to post in a reasonable question, is needed. There's very little "general" advice we can give except that it's not your obligation to do anything about this. Only if you figure out something you can do that will help things (which again is based on tons of specific, minute details), run by a Rabbi who knows you and the situation, would you be potentially "obligated" to do something, but other than that AVOID

@TamirEvan I assure you that he has assured me neither of his parents are a Jew. Not sure how other groups treat non members who claim as members and give them a bad name. I don't think those other groups have to face the level of prejudice Jews have to face, though.

I have long had strong suspicions about the Jewishness of "Jewish" supporters of terrorism.  It sound so much more powerful to say "I am a Jew who supports Hamas" than to say "I support Hamas".  I, for one, believe most of them are not Jews.

@ddas91600 "I assure you that he has assured me neither of his parents are a Jew." That's not clear in the question. When you say in the question "[t]hen he revealed to me that he is actually Messianic", that implies that him being Messianic means he cannot be Jewish. Nowhere in the question do you say that you found out (by other means) that he was not a Jew. That's what prompted my comment.

@ddas91600 "Not sure how other groups treat non members who claim as members and give them a bad name." Simple: Deny he's a member, state that his actions/statements do not represent the group, and present the evidence to that effect. Either the others accept your position, or they prove you wrong, or you've reached an impasse, and there's no use talking to them about it anymore.

Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136664/32959

I know a lot of rabanim say that any "jew" that doesn't exhibit mercy or other traits related to bnei yaakov. Are descendants of the eirev rav who came out of Egypt with us

Okay, so this is definitely a Christian who is not halakhically Jewish, but they think they are a Jew.  Been there!  Keep in mind that this is not a person deliberately trying to bug us.  They are simply in the dark, so they deserve our patience.
I don't think there is any formula that guarantees success, but I will share what I myself would do.
I would find a time that I catch them alone, like we are out for coffee or kicking back at home.  That way there is no embarrassment on their part when you correct them.  Then very tactfully and in a kind voice let them know the you are concerned that they don't understand what a Jew is.  Explain that it is Jewish Law that sets the rules, and the rules are that you either have a Jewish mom or you have made a formal conversion to Judaism.
Assure them that there is nothing wrong with being non-Jewish; that the reason we don't proselytize is that no one really needs to be a Jew.
Then suggest that on rare occasions someone might have such a great affinity for the People of Israel that they do want to join us, even though it means observing 613 laws.  Say something like, "No pressure of course, but if you ever do feel like you are interested in something like that, let me know, and I'll be happy to help."
It is possible that even if you do this with all the tact in the world, that they may still feel offended because of x, y, or z.  For example, someone in their group may have told them they are a Jew and they trust that person.  Or they may simply think they know better than you.
At that point you will need to gauge things for yourself.  How much do you want to push this?  Or is it better to simply let it slide since you almost never see the person?  Only you can be the judge at that point.
I wish you all the best luck in this!  If you can, let us know how it went.'
Shalom.

Wonderful answer

Before I give any advice, I just would like to clarify.
It sounds from your post that this is someone who is not halakhically a Jew, aka his mother is not a Jew.  But he thinks because he attends a Messianic "Judaism" Christian Church that this makes him a Jew.  Is this the case?
A second possibility is that this is a person who is halakhically Jewish, but was not raised Jewish, and doesn't know any better, and has been hoodwinked into thinking that this Christian Church is an appropriate expression of his Yiddishkeit.  I believe such a person is seen as a "captured child," not fully responsible for their actions.
And a third possibility is that it is a case of true apostasy.
I think in all cases, the person should be treated compassionately, but there would obviously be differences in what you might say.
I'll wait for your clarification before I reply further.

It is indeed the case that the person in question is a Christian who call themselves a Messianic Jew

Hello, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Just to point out "requesting additional information" is something that is meant to be done in comments on the question, at [judaism.se] (which you can do once you have 50 reputation). Hope you've had a chance to check out the [tour] and [help] to see how this peculiar site works, and looking forward to your engagement. Don't forget, it's highly encouraged to quote sources, even for subjective questions, round these parts

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. Also, there is nothing wrong if you try to address the question in each of the categories that you mention!
